# Testcafe react selectors

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm confused about how testcafe react selectors actually work. I'm pretty new to JS, so this might be more about me not understanding how `await` works in JS in general.

It seems a little opaque to me about when the react selectors try to fetch their data. I tried to write something like this:

Page Object:

```
export default class ABTestShowPage {
  constructor() {
    this.statsRow = ReactSelector('Row').withProps('name', 'Actions');
  }
}
```

Test:

```
test('Verifies the stats table has "No Actions Available" for completed test', async (t) => {
  const titleLink = abTestIndexPage.getABTestTitleLink('Completed One CTA');

  await t
    .click(titleLink)

  await waitForReact();

  const actionsRow = abTestShowPage.getStatsRow('Actions');

  await t
    .expect(abTestShowPage.statsRow.exists).ok();
});
```

Every time I tried to run the test, I got the following test failure:

```
A/B Test Show
✖ Verifies the stats table has "No Actions Available" for completed test

1) TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined

  Browser: Chrome 69.0.3497 / Mac OS X 10.13.6

     369 |    .click(titleLink)
     370 |
     371 |  await waitForReact();
     372 |
     373 |  await t
   > 374 |    .expect(abTestShowPage.statsActionRow.exists).ok();
     375 |});
     376 |
```

I tried sprinkling `await` in different places but got the same results.

The only way I could get the test to pass was to completely change the structure to look like this:

Page Object:

```
export default class ABTestShowPage {
  constructor() {
    this.statsRow = ReactSelector('Row');
  }

  getStatsRow(rowName) {
    return this.statsRow.withProps('name', rowName);
  }
}
```

Test:

```
test('Verifies the stats table has "No Actions Available" for completed test', async (t) => {
  const titleLink = abTestIndexPage.getABTestTitleLink('Completed One CTA');

  await t
    .click(titleLink)

  await waitForReact();

  const actionsRow = abTestShowPage.getStatsRow('Actions');

  await t
    .expect(actionsRow).ok();
});
```

I've had similar problems where I need to (seemingly randomly) throw in extra `waitForReact` commands or `await`s and I just don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. Why does the first way not calculate the React selector the way I'm expecting it to? The page is fully loaded when I call `waitForReact`, so why does the plain `ReactSelector` not find the component? It feels like I need to add extra complexity to my page object to require functions like this, especially when in this case, it's pretty much single use, because I'm not going to be hunting for other rows in this particular table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've typed 
`abTestShowPage.statsActionRow` 
 instead of 
`abTestShowPage.statsRow`. See the stack trace:

```
     373 |  await t
   > 374 |    .expect(abTestShowPage.statsActionRow.exists).ok();
     375 |});
     376 |
```

Your code is just fine. If you get some other errors with exactly the same code as in your first variant, please update your post and include them.

Comment: That's... extremely embarrassing I have had other issues around the ordering of variable declarations, selectors, and `waitForReact` so I thought this was an instance of that rather than a PEBKAC. What is the general rule about the order of these things? I'm still confused about that.